# how to create valid message object (LPMessage) in Extended MAPI

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mapi

I have existing email client in MFC application (vs2008). I want to save an email to .msg file.
So I investigated and found one [sample](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/171907/info-save-message-to-msg-compound-file)

Searched for reference of LPMessage and found that, they created from existing .msg file or message object.  In my application I dont have message object from which I can build message object. I have to create it from scratch. I am not sure , that I am investigating in right direction or there are other simpler ways also. Can any one help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `StgCreateStorageEx(TGM_CREATE | STGM_TRANSACTED | STGM_READWRITE, STGFMT_DOCFILE)  (or StgCreateDocfile) / OpenIMsgSession / OpenIMsgOnIStg / WriteClassStg`.

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/171907/info-save-message-to-msg-compound-file

Comment: existing email client does not have MAPI. So no existing message in IMessage in format. So I am still not clear how to create valid LPMessage for existing email.

Comment: If there is no MAPI system, where would IMessage come from and what good is it to you if you cannot use it?

Comment: Agreed, but I want to save email in .msg format in email client with no MAPI.

Comment: Then shouldn't be using MAPI interfaces. MSG is an compound (IStorage) file, its format is documented. You will need to create it from the scratch using plain COM.